# How to display output of a python function in horizontal list, so that we can reuse it?

Tags: python, list

```
def prim():
    global network
    co = 0
    for ro in range(sheet.nrows):# 6, 1
           if sheet.cell_value(ro,1)=='Yes':
            prim_cols1 = sheet.cell_value(ro,co)
            network = [prim_cols1]
            print network
prim()
```

Here am reading an input excel and getting output in next byline as:

```
customer,
order,
date
```

but I want to get output in a horizontal line as `'customer', 'order', 'date'` so that I will reuse this output in some other way.

Comment: To cite the documentation of [`print`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#print): "A `'\n'` character is written at the end, unless the `print` statement ends with a comma."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use sys.stdout.write it allows you to control where you put the return character

```
import sys
def prim():
    global network
    co = 0
    for ro in range(sheet.nrows):# 6, 1
           if sheet.cell_value(ro,1)=='Yes':
            prim_cols1 = sheet.cell_value(ro,co)
            network = [prim_cols1]
            sys.stdout.write(str(network)+' ')
    sys.stdout.write('\n')
prim()
```

Comment: Getting error like "sys.stdout.write(network+' ')
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list" . My output is not the list....those are the string values that are read from excel through function.

Comment: Hi did not realize network was an int. I have edited my answer

Comment: Excellent, but am getting output as : [u'Order_id'] [u'name'] [u'amount']....is there any way to get as : order_id, name, amount?

Comment: I guess `network` is in fact a `list`. Have you tried `sys.stdout.write(str(network[0])+' ')` ? And to get rid of `u` which means it is a unicode string you could use sys.stdout.write(network[0].encode("ascii")+' ')`

Comment: I tried with below and i got the perfect output.......thanks alot for your idea...
            network = (prim_cols1).encode('ascii')
            sys.stdout.write(str(network)+','+' ')
    sys.stdout.write('\n')

Comment: Pleasure. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

In Python3 you can add an argument to `print`

```
mylist=["a","b","c"]
def prim():
    # some processing
    for x in mylist:
        # some processing
        print(x,end=" ")
prim()
# a b c
```

Otherwise, append it to an empty string and print that

```
def prim():
    mystring=""
    # some processing
    for x in mylist:
        # some processing
        mystring=mystring+x+" "
    print(mystring)
prim()
# a b c
```

Comment: Getting output as ..Order_id
Order_idname
Order_idname
Order_idname
Order_idnameamount
Order_idnameamount
Order_idnameamount
Order_idnameamount
Order_idnameamount
Order_idnameamount
Order_idnameamount
Order_idnameamount

Answer (score 0):

Stored the data to a list then print the list with `str.join`

```
def prim():
    global network
    co = 0
    networks = []
    for ro in range(sheet.nrows):# 6, 1
        if sheet.cell_value(ro,1)=='Yes':
            prim_cols1 = sheet.cell_value(ro,co)
            network = prim_cols1
            networks.append(network)
    print(" ".join(networks))
    prim()
```

Comment: print(" ".join(networks))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, list found  got this error..

Comment: Oh, because your network is a list, I always think it  is a string. Do you need it to be a string anyway? Fixed the code to work with single string, not list.